# Diagram drawing software for drawing diagrams like this one

Tags: diagrams

Please recommend some diagram drawing software for drawing diagrams like the one below. I prefer software which is much simpler than Photoshop.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned above, you can use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) to produce very nice and vector diagrams (this is advantage - you can export every needed resolution for print)- you can even use many of Public Domain SVG cliparts from sites like Clker.com and put them together in Inkscape and build the diagram. I use this approach often for various illustrations and diagrams and sometimes also for "slides" which I later put in some videos. Inkscape is free and opensource and the Public Domain cliparts can be used free of charge and also freely modified without any problems with license.

Second possibility is to use [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) Draw, which is little bit simpler, but is more focused on such tasks and able to create flowcharts etc. I use it for conference posters etc. (but now create posters also in Inkscape). You can also use here the cliparts from Clker.com, but you will have to download them in PNG format and you will not be able to edit them as much as in Inkscape - only basic raster editing here.

Libreoffice is also free and opensource so you can try both solutions and choose the one which is better for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For something as simple as that, any number of programs will work.  Microsoft Word comes to mind.

I'd also say Visio, but you said something simpler than Photoshop. . .

Comment: Could you please name a few of them? I also prefer open source software. Thanks.

Comment: I just named two.  I'm gonna try the shape tools on LibreOffice here.

Comment: I doubt that we could draw such a diagram in microsoft word. Does microsoft word have rich(if any) image editing features?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get those icons in svg format you should try [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)